# STL List pointers in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, std, bad-alloc

How can I access a list in C++ by de-referencing the List pointer?

I get bad_alloc error when doing:

```
 List My_List = *ls;
```

`ls` is a `List*`. before in code, I had:

```
List* ls = & Temp_List;
```

I used the value of `ls` as an integer. I passed it through different functions. Now that I want to cast it back to `List*` and de-reference it, I get the error

Comment: Is `Temp_List` still alive when you dereference `ls`?

Comment: Is this question about `std::list` or some other list type?  Please clarify the question.

Comment: Should be. Didn't do anything to destroy it.

Comment: Did you use a debugger to check the address of List equals that of Temp_List. Does Temp_List still live? Is Temp_List on the stack? Should it be there? Should you be casting pointers to integers? Are you writing C++ code?

Comment: @Computer_guy If the chain of function calls is immediately following your `List *ls = &Temp_List`, (i.e. Temp_List is still on the stack) then is it conceivable that `sizeof(int) < sizeof(void*)` on your platform? Easy enough to check, but that would definitely cause kerboom. A one-line program could tell you.

Comment: I shouldnt use reference. Because with references, all the list is passed to the function. So the pointer would be enough for passing the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allocate the list on stack, its address might get changed. But if you allocate it on heap, you won't lose the pointer to the list (new or malloc)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see,

```
List *My_List = ls;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you did dereferenced your list pointer in this piece of code: `*ls;`

And then you **created** new list object on the stack in this code:`List My_List` and  **copied** your list into this list in this piece of code: 
`<newly created list> = <your list reference>`

(heh. after applying dereference operator you get the reference. That's c++ for you)

and during this copy you probably get std::bad_alloc because copying lists involves memory allocations, and probably your original list is destroyed and hence your pointer to original list points at some random garbage, and based on this garbage program determines how much memory it should allocate for list copying. So ensure that your original list is still alive.

Or fix your code like this: `List& My_List = *ls` and get a crash somewhere later.

Comment: I think you are right. Somewhere in the code, the first list is destroyed. because earlier I tested the same approach and it gives me the access to the list. But I don't know yet why my initial list has been destroyed!